# Google App Engine custom domain is not activating Google-Managed SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I successfully configure custom domain for my application on Google App Engine. I can access my app by going to : http://www.myapp.com/.

However, on my custom domain dashboard, Google-Managed SSL is getting a lot of time to activate (I have a loading circular progress that is spinning for 2 hours now).

[image]

Before adding custom domain, it says that auto generated SSL can take several minutes to be activated. It has been two hours now. Is it a normal behavior ?

Comment: No, that is not normal.  It usually takes minutes.  I suggest deleting the SSL certs and trying again.

Comment: I just tried that. It's been 1 hour now :(

Comment: Check that you don't have a wrong C record on (@):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292714/google-app-engine-ssl-error-dns-records-could-not-be-found-even-though-custom/60536359#60536359

Comment: Same here....it is been rotating.....FYI, I bought domain from Google domains, so in appengine it is verified domain, I have just mapped it by "continue" button. Concern is, although I have mapped, it is not working......I can browse my app https://projectid.z1.z2.appsopt.com not by domain name. Can you please tell once the certificate installation is done, will I be able to use my domain ?

Comment: You might want to check this out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292714/google-app-engine-ssl-error-dns-records-could-not-be-found-even-though-custom/72019160?noredirect=1#comment133313661_72019160

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the custom domain and retry the process from the beginning (validating, adding the custom domain) and certificates have been generated in 1 minute.

Comment: Same situation here... that's quite frustrating.

Comment: @Jean Col, should I wait 24 before new domains works?

Answer (score 0):

After validating the domain to google DO NOT rush the SSL certificate adding process. Wait one hour or two after validation, then proceed to add the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I have my domain with Google Domains. When adding a subdomain only add the 'sub' portion, e.g. sub.domain.com, only the 'sub' is added as a CNAME record. Same with 'www' for the main domain e.g. [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com). I had previously added 'sub.domian.com' which gcloud App Engine DNS couldn't find.