# Google App Engine SSL error "DNS records could not be found" even though custom domain is working

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, dns

I pointed a new custom domain to a Google App Engine Standard Environment project and edited the DNS records per Google's instructions, and it seems to be redirected properly. Now I'm under the impression that SSL certificates for App Engine projects can now be provided automatically by Let's Encrypt and do not necessarily need to be supplied by the user separately: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl

However, I'm having problem getting the SSL security service from Google. The error message in the App Engine console is: 
    DNS records could not be found. Certificate activation will retry automatically.

This error message looks like this:

[image]

If I type `gcloud beta app domain-mappings list`, I get something that looks like this:

```
ID                    SSL_CERTIFICATE_ID  SSL_MANAGEMENT_TYPE  PENDING_AUTO_CERT
mydomain.com                              AUTOMATIC            1256789
www.mydomain.com      1234567             AUTOMATIC
```

I also tried "Disable managed security" and turn it back on by "Enable managed security", and get the same result after some minutes: "Managed certificate for www.mydomain.com activated." shows up, but not for mydomain.com.

If I go to www.mydomain.com with its supposedly activated certificate, I still get "connection is not secure" in the browser. If I go to "mydomain.com" it gets redirected to www.mydomain.com with the same result.

Any ideas?

Update: I just tried getting my own keys using Certbot and uploaded them to GAE. GAE showed a Certificate ID for both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com. However I had to manually type "https" in the browser to get to the secure page. I found that I had to add "secure: always" in app.yaml before the domain will load the secure version by default. I still don't know why Google's default managed security option didn't work for me though; that would be much more convenient than getting and uploading my own scripts every 3 months.

Comment: wild guess - maybe try the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/q/48189584/4495081?

Comment: does mydomain.com actually have those DNS records that it's saying you need to add? I would check for you but you blacked out the domain (it might be in Cloud DNS or at your web hosting provider). Another possibility is that there was a high TTL on the DNS records before you changed them, only way may be to wait for the old records to expire in that case.

Comment: I tried to do that solution before but the console wouldn't let me re-verify the custom domain (it says the custom domain is already verified and won't let me remove it). I did add the A and AAAA DNS records at my webhost, like "@ 300 IN A 216.239.32.21" and "@ 300 IN AAAA 2001:4860:4802:32::15". The webhost's original TTL was set to expire in 3 hours, but it's been longer than that. How should I check whether the DNS records are actually in place?

Comment: I tried in the App Engine console to remove the problematic mydomain.com but left just www.mydomain.com, and disabling then re-enabling managed security. It says "managed certificate for www.mydomain.com activated" and I get a SSL_CERTIFICATE_ID in the command prompt though not in the web console (same as before). But if I go to www.mydomain.com now I still get "connection is not secure".

Comment: [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#using_your_own_ssl_certificates) says:
If the certificate is for www.example.com you can verify ownership of either www.example.com or example.com

Have you tried leaving only one entry?

Comment: Both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com were verified. Also, that document's section is under "using your own SSL certificates", but I'm not using my own certificate. I did try leaving only www.mydomain.com but that didn't work. Also, in my recent attempt to re-add the custom domain yet again, www.mydomain.com no longer returned a message of success (not that its SSL was ever functional). It just keeps trying to enable SSL security but not succeeding. So now both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com have a PENDING_AUTO_CERT number.

Comment: I just tried getting my own keys from certbot and uploaded them to GAE. I got a Certificate ID for both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com. Still nothing! Connection not secure, the browser says. (Confused)

Comment: Update: it appears that the certbot keys I uploaded did enable SSL, but I had to manually "https" in order to get to the secure page. Instead of this, I found that I had to add "secure: always" in app.yaml before the domain will load the secure version by default. I still don't know why Google's default managed security option didn't work for me though; that would be much more convenient than getting and uploading my own scripts every 3 months.

Answer (score 14):

Ok for anyone still stuck on this:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/
2. Select Settings
3. Add custom domain. select your domain name. (if you have not verified your account before this then do that first)
4. Select the domain you want to add
5. you will get a list of things that you need to create in your hosting acount something like this:
   [image: The addresses from app engine]
6. if you bought your domain name in GoDaddy then you will have to go into your Godaddy account -> YourDomain.com -> DNS -> Manage Zones. Then enter it there thus:
   [image]
7. go back to app engine and click verify.
8. Enjoy!

Comment: It's really useful for me. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 7):

- Go To "App Engine" -> "Settings" -> "Custom Domains"
- Click on "Add Custom Domain"
- Choose the Domain You Want
- You'll end up with something similar that originally brought you to this solution:

  [App Engine Settings With Domain Name SSL Certificate Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFmb.png)

---

- Go to your Domain Registrar (assuming you bought your domain through Google) https://domains.google.com/m/registrar/
- Click on the domain name you'd like to resolve.
- Go to "DNS" -> "Custom resource records" at the bottom
- Fill in the info with the appropriately matching IPv4/IPv6 addresses:

  [Custom Resource Records Where You'll Copy Over Info From App Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69xrx.png)

** Precaution: This is for domain names bought through Google's registrar. If you bought yours elsewhere then the steps may differ.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this same issue recently with GoDaddy, but for me in addition to dangalg's answer, I have to delete the Parked DNS record in GoDaddy to get it resolved.

Comment: this note is tremendously helpful.  I encountered same issue and doing the above resolved for me too

Answer (score 3):

[Igor Kromin's article](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2018/02/01/how-to-fix-the-dns-records-could-not-be-found-error-in-google-app-engine/) outlined the exact same issue that I was having.

I too was / am using CloudFLare's free solution. For some reason Google App Engine didn't immediately recognize the TXT record, so I went ahead and did the alternative CNAME based mapping. Apparently, when you do this, the Cloudflare CNAME flattening kicks in, and *will* do something to the records. When we try to verify domain ownership, it works though. But later, when the APP Engine's Google managed auto-renewing agent looks at the records, somehow they *don't* match up!

Solution is to simply keep trying to verify the TXT record which Cloudflare doesn't modify, and then it works out.

**Tip**: If you're trying to verify a subdomain to app engine like api.yourdomain.com, your TXT record needs to be with the `api` domain name, not at `@` like normal.

Comment: This isn't about verifying the domain. It's about getting Google App Engine to issue the certificates AFTER the domain is verified

Comment: Thanks it was very unclear that they wanted all the records on the sub domain, working now

Answer (score 2):

Came across the same issue. Steps I took including the steps by @Rajasegar:

1. Removed Parked DNS record from GoDaddy DNS console.
2. Make sure you are logged in to the correct project by running the command below.

```
gcloud config list
```

- Check the output:

  ```
    [core] 
    account = [youremail@mail.com]
    disable_usage_reporting = True  
    project = [your-project]
  ```

3. Run `domain-mappings update` command from terminal to update the cert on mydomain with the cert-management set to AUTO

```
gcloud app domain-mappings update 'mydomain.com' --certificate-management=AUTOMATIC
```

Took few seconds for me to see the updated cert for the naked domain in the Custom Domains properties.

Comment: #1 and #3 are quite important. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In my case I accidentally created a C record for the naked domain (@) in addition to the www. subdomain which should exclusively have it. As there can't be a TXT record on the same level as a C record, the verification failed. Totally my bad but maybe anyone else is also having such issues.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that Google didn't generate a certificate for my naked domain, but did generate one for my www domain. It would give the same error: DNS records could not be found. I had configured the domains years before, but it started failing to update the certificate for the naked domain without any explanation. Just removing the certificate and re-enabling didn't help. What eventually got it working was to **remove the naked domain from the custom domains list, then readd it**.