# Can't add custom naked domain mapping after deleting the old one

Tags: ssl, google-app-engine, dns, mapping

The naked domain stopped working, and gave me a 404 error. `www` domain worked fine. I ended up deleting both the naked domain and "www" domain from the custom domain settings and adding them again. The naked domain suddenly disappeared from that page. I only see the "www" domain there. (tried disabling cache and etc)

[image: custom domain settings]

I have been trying to recreate the mapping for the naked domain, and it is giving me this error.

[image: naked domain recreate mapping]

It seems like it is trying to process in the background but when I click override and continue, nothing happens. I don't see a naked domain mapping in the custom domains tab. When I go to naked domain url, `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` error. Added an uptime check and it shows the following error:

`Responded with "SSL Handshake Error" in 10,000 ms.`

I purchased the domain from Google Domains, the DNS settings are set. Using google-managed SSL.

**UPDATE:**

The mapping is finally visible but the SSL certificate didn't work so still can't access.

`DNS records could not be found. Certificate activation will retry automatically.`

[image: ssl error]

Comment: If you get `404` error then DNS resolution from domain name to IP address works and the problem is most probabaly in your web server setting.

Comment: I was getting 404 before I removed and tried recreating mappings. Now I get "This site can’t be reached" 

Uptime check test gives me:
Responded with "SSL Handshake Error" in 10,000 ms.

Comment: The domain name was resolved, and your web server has some certificate problem.

Comment: For some reasons you hide from us public domain name, it makes hard to help you.

Comment: oh it is datasourced.net . I wasn't sure if it is ok to share website urls

Comment: Looks like there is an SSL certification issue. I updated the image above, the warning says "DNS records could not be found. "

Comment: Try to follow these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60060490/15803365) and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This resolved itself after waiting for a day. The naked domain now has a valid certificate.