# 404 Error When trying to obtain managed certificate on google app engine

Tags: go, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get a managed certificate to make my app engine application accessible from a custom domain. I managed to add the domain, and I also created the DNS records. However, now I'm running into a problem: The custom domain is stuck in the "certificate being activated" state. I checked my logs, and it seems that the google certificate service is making GET requests to my app, under `.well-known/acme-challenge/<challenge string>`. These are returning 404, because my app isn't set up to respond on that URL.
[image: certificate being activated]
[image]

The app is built in Go, and the `app.yaml` has the following content (environment variables are omitted).

```
runtime: go120  # or another supported version
app_engine_apis: true

env_variables:
  MY_VAR: 'my-val'
  ...
```

Is there something else I need to set up? Do I somehow need to redirect the acme challenge requests to a google service? I haven't been able to find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It randomly started working after waiting for two hours. I love the cloud...

Answer (score 1):

This has been an issue for others as well, it's fortunate in your case that it was resolved by itself after some time. In other cases, what was needed was to reconfigure everything again (remove custom domain, add custom domain, validate. I've found 2 identical cases That were resolved by the said method.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306324/constant-request-of-acme-challenge-file-on-appengine-from-google
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189584/google-app-engine-custom-domain-is-not-activating-google-managed-ssl

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by logging out from all my Single sign-on sessions(Login with gmail etc) and it worked